# Problems creating log file of mono-service assembly output

Tags: ubuntu, logs, mono

When we start in the `mono-service` mode on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 in the background, we would like to create and store a log file at wherever the user wants. I tried this URL,
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11024474/capture-mono-service-stdout-console-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024474/capture-mono-service-stdout-console-output)

where it says do this:

```
mono-service2 myservice.exe -l:/var/run/test --debug > log.txt
```

which does not work when I test the following C++ program:

```
#include <unistd.h>     // execv(), fork()
#include <sys/types.h>  // pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h>   // waitpid()
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argvp)
{
   char *argv[] = { "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe", 
                    "SmartCamXi_NVR_Recorder.exe", "--debug", "'>&'","/home/venkat/LOGCamster.txt", 0};


    char *envp[] =
    {
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/venkat/Debug",
        0
    };
    execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
    return -1;

}
```

because I observe no log file being created. How could I fix this error?

Comment: Is your C program the thing that you are calling as `mono-service2`? Or `myservice.exe`? Please [edit] your question to make that clear.

Comment: @roaima, Thanks for the comment. Myservice.exe is a C# executable. mono-service2 is a C++ utility program written by Xamarin and Microsoft to support Mono Linux deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C program performs the equivalent of this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
exec /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe Audio_Video_Recorder.exe --debug '>&' LOGCamster.txt
echo "Oops!" >&2
exit 255
```

Notice that the `>&` and `LOGCamster.txt` are passed as literal arguments to your command line. Specifically, `>&` is *not* interpreted by the shell to mean "attach *stderr* to *stdout*" because there is no shell handling your command line.

The chances are that the program doesn't like the '>&' parameter it's being given and exits immediately.

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `.`, opens up a potentially huge security hole. I really wouldn't do that if I were you.

---

If you really need to do this from an executable then you can do one of two things

1. Redirect *stdout* and *stderr* yourself. Here you'll need to `close(1)` and then `open()` to your log file. You can then `close(2)` and `dup(1)`. After this just `execve` your program without trying to redirect the output anywhere - because it's already being redirected to the log file.
2. Call a shell to interpret your command. Here you need three arguments: `char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "mono-service.exe Audio_Recorder.exe --debug >& log.txt" }`. However, if you're doing this you really might as well use a script, which is easier to write and more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice answer. I am dumping the LD_LIBRARY_PATH = . , because it is a big security hole. Also, I see no file named LOGCamster.txt being created. Could you please show me how to correct my program ? Are you suggesting I ditch the redirection operator >&?

Comment: @Frank I must apologise - I misread your code. I have rewritten my answer to take account of my new interpretation so please check that my answer is still appropriate for you.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent comment. I revised my original C++ program , shown at the bottom of the original question. It still not generate LOGCamster.txt. May I request that you take a look at it and  possibly suggest corrections to it?

Comment: It looks like you've adjusted `>&` so that the parameter is now the four characters `'>&'`. The fundamental problem is that `>&` cannot do what you want (i.e. to redirect _stderr_ to _stdout_) because you're not invoking a shell to parse it. May I ask what you're trying to achieve with your C program that can't be handled in a couple of lines of shell script?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your idea of a couple lines of shell script is great. However, My manager wants me to write a C++ program to start the C#  executable, Audio_Recorder.exe, as a service and also create and write a log file in an user-specified location. How might I do that? I tried char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh",  "mono-service.exe", "Audio_Recorder.exe", "--debug", ">&", "log.txt",0) followed by execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp) with no success.

Comment: @Frank try that; I've updated the answer for you